# svmono v5.6 doesn't like unnamed labeled examples

Tags: environments, examples, sv-classes

Put

```
\documentclass{svmono}%%% v5.6 from http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/rights-permissions-licensing/manuscript-preparation/5636
\begin{document}
\begin{example}\label{e}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

into `file.tex`. Running `pdflatex` on it produces

```
$ pdflatex file
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./file.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(./svmono.cls
Document Class: svmono 2018/06/25 v5.6 
Springer Verlag global LaTeX document class for monographs
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/x11nam.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.sty
Style `ntheorem', Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)))
No file file.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 3.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> file

?
```

What's wrong? Is there any way to hack svmono to correct it?  Of course, the above example is very minimal. In reality, you'd have other packages and text around and inside the environment. A simple workaround would be providing an empty text: `\begin{example}{}\label{e}\end{example}`, but this would go against the fact that `example` in §2.6 of `refguide.pdf` (dated 2019-02-05) is declared as taking no arguments or one (optional) argument. I'm wondering whether it's possible to correct svmono such that it behaves as usual, which is printing simply

> *Example 1.*

The previous class version (svmono v5.5) succeeds without problems in this situation.

(PS. Plz don't lambast me too much: I cannot get Springer's help directly first-hand; my prior e-mails have been rejected on the SMTP level. So, if anyone from Springer reads here: plz see @moewe's answer and improve, e.g, by removing the redefinition in lines 1980-1981.)

Comment: You probably need to read the manual. `example` now takes a mandatory argument and isn't too happy using `\label` for this. You can test it if you replace `\label` with `test`, then the `t` is used for some kind of headline.

Comment: I looked at the code, it is not. I just looked in the manual and it does not seem to be documented there, `example` is listed along side `theorem`, which behaves differently.

Comment: The `example` environment is first defined as a theorem like construction on line 1498 and then redefined to take a mandatory argument on line 1980 of `svmono.cls`

Comment: Seems to be an oversight. The class defines `example` twice: Once with `\spn@wtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}` as all other theorem-like environments and then later it does `\renewenvironment{example}[1]` which means that `example` takes a mandatory argument.

Comment: You can get back the theorem-like definition with `\makeatletter
\let\example\relax
\spn@wtheorem{example}{Example}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\makeatletter`

Comment: Don't touch the CLS file.

Comment: Springer usually still  wants the code.

Comment: Note that Springer (like most professional publishers) does not use your code for the actual typesetting. As stated on the Manuscript preparation page: "**Note:** These templates are not intended for the preparation of the final page layout! The final layout will be created by Springer according to our layout specifications." Of course they still may look at your source code if something is not clear, but any changes you make to the layout are just for your own viewing.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any mail address for bug reports in the downloaded files. The only thing I could find says *Please direct any queries concerning your book project to your contact person at Springer. He or she will be happy to respond directly or pass on your query to the expert in charge.* in the author instructions. Since you are writing a Springer book I assume you must have some kind of contact with them, maybe it is enough to pass on the information via that channel. Certainly better than hoping they read this Q&A.

Comment: @user49915 there is no disagreement as far as I can tell - I just wanted to point out that, unlike for example papers submitted to conferences, for books it is not very important how you supply your material (using `svmono`, or the `book` class, as mentioned on the Springer website, or Microsoft Word) and which modifications you make to the appearance, because the publisher has their own typesetting department which will take your input and format it according to their standards. This also means that any non-conforming changes you make will be undone.

Comment: Also, when you publish a book with Springer there is a communication process (usually by e-mail) in which you will be asked and guided to modify your sources, provide your image files in a different way, etc., until the manuscript is suitable for publication.

Comment: you don't need to write an email to report the bug. Apart from the old fashioned method to write a letter: they have contact forms on their website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svmono.cls` defines `example` twice. Once in a theorem-like manner in line 1498 with

```
\spn@wtheorem{example}{Example}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
```

presumably this is the documented definition.

Later on in the block `%%%SOPHIE TEMPLATE BEGIN%%%` in ll. 1980-1981 the class does

```
\renewenvironment{example}[1]{\ignorespaces\def\stmtopen##1{##1}%
\formtmp{example}{#1}}{\par\noindent\textcolor{example}{\rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}}\vskip2pt\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}%
```

Which redefines `example` and in particular means that it now takes a mandatory argument. This is exactly what becomes problematic in the MWE because the `\label` is now absorbed as the mandatory argument.

Sophie's template is a new addition for version 5.6 of `svmono.cls`.

You can get back the presumably intended definition by adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\example\relax
\spn@wtheorem{example}{Example}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\makeatletter
```

to your preamble. Of course you could also comment out the unwanted `\renewenvironment{example}`.

A similar effect can be observed for `question`.

---

This looks like a bug in the class (or in the documentation) and it should be reported to the maintainer (SMTP failure or otherwise).